# C# port.write(ENQ), scale turn off and receive null

Tags: c#, serial-port, port, scale

I try connect to scale via rs232 cable. When I try write "ENQ" to port then scale turn off and receive nothing. This is my code. Sorry my bad English :(

```
class ScaleCAS
{
            private SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            public string result = null;

            public ScaleCAS()
            {
                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
                port.Open();
            }

            private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                this.result = port.ReadExisting();
            }
}
```

**ADD**

In another class I try write into port

```
Scale.port.write("ENQ");
Console.Write(Scale.result);
```

Comment: The posted code cannot be used to reproduce the problem, please add how you attempt to write to the port

Comment: port.write("ENQ") this way

Comment: You probably need to send the ASCII code for ENQ not the string. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188324/how-to-communicate-with-scale-via-rs232

Comment: I try port.write(5) same result :(

Comment: There isn't a SerialPort Write method that allows "port.write(5)" are you sure you didn't use port.write("5")  - see the very bottom answer. If that fails check out the LookRS232 utility or similar & see if you can successfully communicate with the scales using that.

Comment: I send port.write(5)

Comment: byte[] Buff = new byte[1];
            Buff[0] = 0x05;
            this.scale.port.Write(Buff, 0, 1);

Comment: I also tried this way

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for your scale to answer, you read the value of `result` a way lot faster then it get filled with data.

A good way to communicate using SerialPort is with [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) and [WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx), check out that [NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) was set correctly according to you device programming manual (which would be nice to add to the question if you are asking question about specific device).

Some general troubleshooting of RS232 communications:

- Check baud rate and all other serial port configuration
- Check what is the EOL (End of Line) character, and use it to terminate writing statements and to know how to stop reading input messages (or use ReadLine and WriteLine)
- Check the communication manually using TeraTerm or some other serial terminal

Comment: I want to connect scale TSCALE TSQSP via CAS protocol. Do you have same sample

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188324/how-to-communicate-with-scale-via-rs232).

Comment: exactly I use this code for my project, problem is when I try send "ENQ" "5" or everything else, that scale turning off :(